# app router in Express

Tags: node.js, express

There currently is a difference between

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){

});
```

and

```
router.use('/some_route', function(req,res,next){

});
```

...The difference being that `app.use` runs for every request and `router.use` only runs for matching routes.

My question is about the router that must lie underneath app. Surely app has some default router internal to it. Is there a way to access that router...app.router? I thought that was deprecated?

Secondly, what I am really looking for is a way to access the current router being used.

For example,

```
   app.use(function(req,res,next){

      var currentRouter = req.app._router // (?)

     });
```

or

```
    router.use(function(req,res,next){

         var currentRouter = req._router //(?)

    });
```

where req._router would be equal to the same router for the router.use call of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [latest Express code](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L136), the default app router is in `app._router`.

It is created lazily which means it's not created until a route is actually defined (with `app.use()` or `app.get()` or something like that).

It does not appear that this is meant to be a public property and thus is subject to change.  You can, of course, just define your own router with the root path and only use your own router and then you would not have to access or use this non-public property.

You are correct that `app.router` is deprecated.  Trying to access it purposely throws an exception in the Express code.

Comment: thanks for the info, the reason I asked the question is because I am creating an Express middleware lib (the rate limiting one) and I dont want to have to require the user of my lib to explicitly pass "app" or "router" to the function that creates my middleware handler...but it looks like it has to be explicit

Comment: so what I am really looking for is a way to get the current router that is handling the current middleware...if there is a way to get at that

Comment: @AlexMills - Next time you post a question, please include the REAL reason behind your question.  I answered the question you asked and now you've edited it into a new question.  That is not how stack overflow works.

Comment: yeah sorry that was my mistake

Comment: @AlexMills - A middleware handler gets three arguments passed to it.  I don't see anything in those three arguments that can be used to connect to the router that the middleware is attached to.  The next obvious question would be why you're trying to get to that router?  That is probably the real problem you're trying to solve.  You can get so much more meaningful answers if you describe the real problem you're trying to solve.  When you ask questions that are far down a path of a particular solution, all we can do is help you in that one little corner of the solution space.

Comment: you have it right..if you look for the "curtain" lib on NPM, you see that my ratelimiter can allow for the inclusion/ exclusion of particular routes. So instead of rate limiting every route for a user hitting one server, we can ignore some routes - likewise if want to include routes exclusively. either way I dont know how to code that feature *without* a direct handle on the router being used in the part of the code where they invoke my lib. The feature works as is but I would like to improve the api of the lib potentially but not requiring the user to pass app/router to me.

Comment: @AlexMills - In this "curtain", https://github.com/ORESoftware/curtain, I don't see where you're trying to look at specific routes or where the code would want access to the router object?  And, if you are wanting to do that somewhere, I don't see why you don't juts change your API to take the router and have your API attach the middleware to the router itself (and remember the router they passed you).

Comment: yeah that's what I am doing - before I return function(req,res,next) in my middleware, I check for the include/exclude routes and that's how I decide whether to assign req.curtainOnly and req.curtainSkip.

Comment: my code works as is, but what I am looking for is a way to eliminate the need for the user to have to explicitly pass a router instance...in other words my lib should already know about the context of where it was invoked..somehow

Comment: I will add some more comments to the curtain lib, it should be clear as day after that

Comment: @AlexMills - I see it in the code now.  I'm looking at options.

Comment: ok yeah I think it might be impossible...the "this" context in my lib is an instance of my lib itself...router might have to be a good old fashioned argument...more than anything because I want to do the route inclusion/exclusion check outside of the middleware itself for performance reasosn but inside my code

Comment: @AlexMills - The router object is simply not known to the middleware handler.  Instead of adding middleware handlers for the exception routes just so you can set a flag on them, you could just check the given request URL yourself to see if it matches any of the exception routes.  This would require copying how Express matches a route, but Express uses the path-to-regexp library to do that so you could also.

Comment: ahh good to know, yeah I will check out the path-to-regexp lib, thanks!!